# i am setting value of threadlocal in one class can i access the value in another class

Tags: java

in the below code i am storing temporary threadlocal values in a threadlocal class.and set the value into another class..

```
List<String> spaces=new ArrayList<String>();
spaces.add(spaceKey);
ThreadLocal<List<String>> threadLocal=new ThreadLocal<List<String>>();
threadLocal.set(spaces);  
setShardHolder(threadLocal);
```

i have getters and setters in another class

```
private ThreadLocal<List<String>> shardHolder;
public ThreadLocal<List<String>> getShardHolder() {
return shardHolder;
}
public void setShardHolder(ThreadLocal<List<String>> shardHolder) {
this.shardHolder = shardHolder;
}
```

i am not able to access the values using the getter

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 20):

You don't seem to have understood how ThreadLocal variables work. A ThreadLocal instance is a bit like a container for a single value. If you store something in it, it will be associated to the current thread, and you can retrieve it later, from the same thread.

But of course, if you store something in a ThreadLocal instance, and try to retrieve it from a different ThreadLocal instance, you'll always get null: they're not the same container.

So a ThreadLocal is often hidden behind static methods. Suppose you want to associate a user with the current thread, for example. You would do

```
public class CurrentUser {
    private static final ThreadLocal<User> CURRENT = new ThreadLocal<User>();

    public static User getCurrentUser() {
        return CURRENT.get();
    }

    public static void setCurrentUser(User user) {
        CURRENT.set(user);
    }
}
```

Then let's design a scenario :

```
public class Test
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CurrentUser.set(new User("foo"));
        System.out.println(CurrentUser.get()); // prints foo
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(CurrentUser.get()); // prints null: different thread
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To get the value of any object you need to have a reference to it.  Provided you can reference the ThreadLocal in a class you can access it. (There is nothing special about ThreadLocal in that regard)

I suggest you try it.

> i am not able to access the values using the getter

This means you doing something wrong, but since you haven't said why you cannot do this, it's not clear what that is.

If you are saying you can get a ThreadLocal, but calling it return `null`, this means you are running this in another thread.  This is what ThreadLocal is designed to do.

Answer (score 1):

From the javadoc, `ThreadLocal` instances are typically private static fields in classes that wish to associate state with a thread. Ex:

```
    private static final ThreadLocal<List<String>> SHARD_HOLDER;
    public static List<String> getSpacesList() {
        return SHARD_HOLDER.get();
    }

    public static void setSpacesList(List<String> spacesList) {
        SHARD_HOLDER.set(spacesList);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set your thread local as a static variable and use it that way, have a look at this article im sure one of the examples will suit your use case.

http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-thread-local-%E2%80%93-how-use