# Share some variable between annotated method and aspect

Tags: java, annotations, aspectj, spring-aop, aspect

I want to audit some method that annotated with some annotation like `audited`. Now in aspect that select the annotated method I generate some `UUID`. I want to share this `UUID` between method and aspect. In first solution I can generate this `UUID` and pass it to annotated method but in this way lot of method signature may be changed. Is there any way to pass it from aspect to method?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ThreadLocals as mentioned in the link.[ThreadLocals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17615487/4011142)

Are you using Spring MVC and also please shed some light on how are you going to use UUID in the annotated method which you want?